# CSS Tumblr Theme: Post2 Background Misplaced

Tags: css, background, tumblr, overlap, overlapping

I don't know the right term but I hope someone could help me fix this up. The background isn't fixed with the border.

I can't really explain how it looks like so please [click here](http://i.imgur.com/5UwUBIT.jpg) for the imgur uploaded image of my problem.

For the code I used, please [click here](http://laboumph.tumblr.com/) to be directed on my Tumblr. Right click and select "view page source".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to modify the padding for the post div.

Change this

```
.post{
   width: 450px;
   padding: 7px;
   background-color:#FFCCCC;
   margin-bottom:0px; 
   margin-top:5px;
   margin-left: 10px;
   border:1px dashed #f0e5c4;
}
```

to

```
.post{
   width: 450px;
   padding-right: 11px;
   background-color:#FFCCCC;
   margin-bottom:0px; 
   margin-top:5px;
   margin-left: 10px;
   border:1px dashed #f0e5c4;
}
```